# Why is a simple Binary classification failing in a feedforward neural network?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, feed-forward

I am new to Pytorch. I was trying to model a binary classifier on the Kepler dataset. The following was my dataset class.

```
class KeplerDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, test=False):
        self.dataframe_orig = pd.read_csv(koi_cumm_path)

        if (test == False):
            self.data = df_numeric[( df_numeric.koi_disposition == 1 ) | ( df_numeric.koi_disposition == 0 )].values
        else:
            self.data = df_numeric[~(( df_numeric.koi_disposition == 1 ) | ( df_numeric.koi_disposition == 0 ))].values

        self.X_data = torch.FloatTensor(self.data[:, 1:])
        self.y_data = torch.FloatTensor(self.data[:, 0])

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.X_data[index], self.y_data[index]
```

Here, I created a custom classifier class with one hidden layer and a single output unit that produces sigmoidal probability of being in class 1 (planet).

```
class KOIClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, out_dim):
        super(KOIClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, 32)

        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(32, 32)

        self.linear3 = nn.Linear(32, out_dim)


    def forward(self, xb):
        out = self.linear1(xb)
        out = F.relu(out)
        out = self.linear2(out)
        out = F.relu(out)
        out = self.linear3(out)
        out = torch.sigmoid(out)

        return out
```

I then created a `train_model` function to optimize the loss using SGD.

```
def train_model(X, y):
    criterion = nn.BCELoss()

    optim = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

    n_epochs = 100
    losses = []

    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        y_pred = model.forward(X)
        loss = criterion(y_pred, y)
        losses.append(loss.item())
        optim.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optim.step()

losses = []
for X, y in train_loader:
    losses.append(train_model(X, y))
```

But after performing the optimization over the train_loader, When I try predicting on the trainn_loader itself, the prediction values are so much worse.

```
for features, y in train_loader:
    y_pred = model.predict(features)
    break

y_pred


> tensor([[4.5436e-02],
        [1.5024e-02],
        [2.2579e-01],
        [4.2279e-01],
        [6.0811e-02],
        .....
```

Why is my model not working properly? Is it the problem with the dataset or am I doing something wrong with implementing the Neural net? I will [link](https://www.kaggle.com/shiladityabasu/openexa) my Kaggle notebook because more context might be helpful. Please help.

Comment: Inside of the `train_model` function, you should iterate over the values on the `train_loader`, on the last loop that you should loop over the epochs. I don't know if this is the only issue, this may be the problem.

Comment: Are you applying the SS to categorical data? From your notebook it looks like the disposition values are also being scaled which could mess things up. Also, I couldn't tell from the notebook which column you were trying to predict, you say binary classifier but the disposition column goes from 0 to 2.

Comment: @todofwar no I have excluded the disposition col and 4 other flags col and started an in place scaling from col 5, here `df_numeric.iloc[:, 5:] = std_scaler.fit_transform(df_numeric.iloc[:, 5:])
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are optimizing many times (100 steps) on the first batch (first samples), then moving to the next samples. It means that your model will overfit your few samples before going to the next batch. Then, your training will be very non smooth, diverge and go far from your global optimum.

Usually, in a training loop you should:

1. go over all samples (this is one epoch)
2. shuffle your dataset in order to visit your samples in a different order (set your pytorch training loader accordingly)
3. go back to 1. until you reach the max number of epochs

Also you should not define your optimizer each time (nor your criterion).

Your training loop should look like this:

```
criterion = nn.BCELoss()
optim = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
n_epochs = 100

def train_model():
    for X, y in train_loader:
        optim.zero_grad()
        y_pred = model.forward(X)
        loss = criterion(y_pred, y)
        loss.backward()
        optim.step()

for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    train_model()
```

Comment: This sort of fixed it. I ran SGD with `lr = 0.01` with 10 epochs first, but the output prediction had the same value (with minor changes) for all the rows. But after I ran for 1000 epochs, the probabilities started to change a bit. like `[[0.0034],
        [0.0043],
        [0.0036],
        [0.9658],
        [0.0032],
        ...
Is this a normal thing that the model initially produces the same probabilities for all rows and gradually starts to stabilize on some rows with higher probs and low for others with more epochs? or should the uneven distribution start from the beginning?

Comment: This highly depends on your optimization problem. But yes, during first iterations the model tends to produce similar probabilities but it must converge as long as it learns from your data.

Comment: One other thing. Should I use ReLU instead of sigmoid? will that make any difference? Or maybe use a mixture of them, something like alternating the activation functions in different hidden layers?

Comment: Usually, ReLU is used in between network layers as activation function to create non linearities. The final layer depends on your problem, the sigmoid layer you are using is relevant if you want to output values in [0, 1].